# What's in an [application-name]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across a question tagged with [application-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-name). On investigation, there is no guidance on the tag and there appears to be no real consistency in the usage.

There's only 39 questions tagged with it covering a range of different technologies from [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) to [elmah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elmah) and [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios).

It seems like these questions are already being properly served by the additional tags relating to their specific technologies.

Could/Should this tag be burninated?

Comment: #hashtag #tagsarenot #hashtags #hashtag

Comment: @Braiam I think you mean `[hashtag]`. :P

Comment: Seems to me the vast majority of questions are asking about issues with the actual name of their application within a programming environment. This seems akin to having a [function-name] tag asking about issues with function names. Burninate with full fury, I say.

Comment: *cocks shotgun*